# Body as form data in node.js is undefined through postman Mongodb

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, postman, bson

I am trying to do a post request to the server through form-data, but i need two fields to be added as body.

I have to add the following fields in my body:

sporter - type: text

file - type: file

But when i do: `console.log(req.body.file)` or `console.log(req.body.sporter)` both return undefined. I know i can fix it by using raw json, but is there a way to input the binary file through postman? Because you cant do it with raw json. Or is there a way to make the form-data work?

Comment: shouldn't it be `req.body.file`?

Comment: @TalhaAwan changed it